# How Do I Create an Extension of a Single Class Property

Tags: vb.net

I have a primitive Class that looks like this:

```
Public Class BaseGeoData
    Property GeoOrigin As String
    Property GeoDestination As String
    Property TravelDistance As Double?
    Property TravelTime As Double?

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class GeoData
 Inherits BaseGeoData
   Public Sub New(geoOrigStr As String, geoDestStr As String)
       GeoOrigin = geoOrigStr
       GeoDestination = geoDestStr
       TravelDistance = 5000      'in meters
       TravelTime = 360           'in minutes
   End Sub
End Class
```

I want to be able to add 2 extensions that will return converted values like this:

```
TravelDistance.ToMiles()   
TravelTime.ToHours()
```

When I add a Module to extend the class, it offers the extension to the entire class, most properties of which will never use the extension. How can I just offer the extensions to the properties that need them?

Comment: You can't. You can only create extensions for the classes and structures themselves. You'd have to make an extension method to `Double?` if you want to be able to do that, although it will of course apply to _every_ `Double?`.

Comment: Ugh. Well at least I now know that I wasn't missing something simple. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Why not just create methods to return the miles or time for a given instance?

Answer (score 1):

Introduce own type of "Unit" for measurement values

```
Public MustInherit Class Unit
    Public ReadOnly Property Value As Double

    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Name As String

    Public Sub New(value As Double)
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Value} {Name}"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Meter
    Inherits Unit

    Public Sub New(value As Double)
        MyBase.New(value)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return "m"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Mile
    Inherits Unit

    Public Sub New(value As Double)
        MyBase.New(value)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return "mi"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And extension methods for creating unit and convertions

```
Public Module UnitConversions

    <Extension>
    Public Function Meters(value As Integer) As Meter
        Return New Meter(value)
    End Function

    <Extension>
    Public Function Miles(value As Integer) As Mile
        Return New Mile(value)
    End Function

    <Extension>
    Public Function ToMiles(meters As Meter) As Mile
        Dim miles = meters.Value * 0.00062137
        Return New Mile(miles)
    End Function

    <Extension>
    Public Function ToMeters(miles As Mile) As Meter
        Dim meters = miles.Value * 1609.344
        Return New Meter(meters)
    End Function
End Module
```

Then you can use value in more readable manner

```
TravelDistance = 5000.Meters() ' meters

' Conversion
geoData.TravelDistance.ToMiles() ' miles

Console.WriteLine(geoData.TravelDistance) ' print 3.10685 mi
```

Comment: Nice answer! Though shouldn't the two first extension methods extend `Double` rather than `Integer`? (Or both)

Comment: @VisualVincent, yes, but I used integer for better readability, because with double it will look like `10.0.Meters()` and not used `Double` to keep answer smaller. In actual application I would have both of them

Answer (score 0):

You can only add extension methods into types (i.e. classes).

`TravelDistance` is of type `Double?` so you have to add an extention method into `Double?`.

Note that it would make the method available for every `Double?`, which may not be something you want.

Answer (score 0):

I really like **Plutonix's** resolution and is the same one I would go for first.

Its simple and resolves your initial problem.

```
Public Class BaseGeoData

  Property GeoOrigin As String
  Property GeoDestination As String
  Property TravelDistance As Double?
  Property TravelTime As Double?

  Public Sub New()
  End Sub

End Class


Public Class GeoData
  Inherits BaseGeoData

  Public Sub New(geoOrigStr As String, geoDestStr As String)
    GeoOrigin = geoOrigStr
    GeoDestination = geoDestStr
    TravelDistance = 5000      'in meters
    TravelTime = 360           'in minutes
  End Sub

  Function DistanceMiles() As Double
    DistanceMiles = (TravelDistance/1609.344)
  End Function

  Function TimeHours() As Double
    DistanceMiles = (TravelTime /60)
  End Function

End Class
```